# Why visual studio 2013 installer installs everything

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Ok,

So something must be wrong. I just downloaded vs 2013 community edition, and when I unchecked the C++ options and press the install button, after a while I catch it downloading c++ x64/x86 libraries. I bet 10 dollars the functionality will be available.

When I used a "pirate"copy of professional, when installing update 4, the installer make himself comfortable and just download windows 8 phone sdk images and files...

Anyone can tell this is normal?

**Update**

I really enjoy visual studio, iam not gonna lie, it makes life easier. If we had something like sublime , I know the package sizes are not the same, but they could have done better I guess. I have 12 packages of sql server and the chances of using it are very remote.

Comment: It is confirmed... visual studio officially installed c++ when I unchecked the option, choosing not to install... god dammit.

Comment: The C++ libraries are required for VS to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood the Optional Features set of the Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition Installer. The installer does not give you the option of which languages to install, but only the option to choose which additional libraries and tools to install.

[image: VS2013 Community Edition Optional Features]

The Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++ option is not an option for choosing whether to install C++ or not, but the option to install the [Microsoft Foundation Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library), which is a library that wraps portions of the Windows API with C++ classes. In other words an addition to the basic C++ install that is a required part of the Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Comment: To be honest, your question isn't worded in the most constructive manner, which I would say would be the main reason for the negative  voting. It has the tone that you have come here to complain about something rather than to seek assistance to a problem. If you have come here to ask for general help, than I suggest you make sure to leave any cynicism and snidely remarks at the door. Then you will will receive the best help.